# How can I display my resid() output as a normal dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to plot residuals from a linear regression model to another plot.

I've calculated the residuals like so:

```
x <- df$CDS_GC3
y<- df$tRNA_GC
m1 <- lm(y~x)
res <- resid(m1)
```

but my output looks like this

```
          1            2            3          
 -4.32569462  10.55395491   5.79337634
```

etc. I would like to have it in a column format, with the numbers on the left and values on the right.

How can I convert it into such a data frame? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `dfresid <- data.frame(resid = resid(m1))`. Note: `m1 <- lm(tRNA_GC ~ CDS_GC3, data = df)` avoids duplicating the data in your R session.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in `t()` to transpose the output.